# Problem deploying project on Firebase with Stripe

Tags: firebase, stripe-payments, firebase-tools, google-secret-manager

I'm trying to deploy my app that has the stripe payment extension installed. Everything works fine on the emulator (I am not using stripe for the moment) but when I try to deploy everything looks ok except deploy fails with this message:

```
Error: firestore-stripe-payments: Found
'projects/1234/secrets/ext-firestore-stripe-payments-STRIPE_API_KEY/versions/1'
for secret param STRIPE_API_KEY, but this instance was previously
using a different secret
projects/1234/secrets/firestore-stripe-payments-STRIPE_API_KEY.
Changing secrets is not supported. If you want to change the value of
this secret, use a new version of
projects/1234/secrets/firestore-stripe-payments-STRIPE_API_KEY.You
can create a new version at
https://console.cloud.google.com/security/secret-manager?project=1234
```

So I go to the link without knowing how my emulator API key works compared to the production one ( I didn't activated the Stripe account ). Here I find two keys, one is `firestore-stripe-payments-STRIPE_API_KEY` and the other one is `ext-firestore-stripe-payments-STRIPE_API_KEY`. When I click to make a new version it asks for a file with a secret.

So my main problem is: do I need to change version of both two secrets or only one? Second problem is where do I find those keys and does the test API key work on deployment?

Am I missing something here, am I on the right path?

Comment: One key is for the Stripe Webhook (incoming calls). The other is the key for the Stripe API (outgoing calls). Both kinds of keys are managed in the Stripe Dashboard. Also, it is easy to confuse TEST and LIVE Stripe key sets.

Comment: @Dabbel Many thanks for your answer how can I solve my problem with the deploy?